# how to scope the SharedViewModel after migrating an existing app to use the Navigation component

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I've been struggling on this the whole day and still can't make it work. In an existing Single Activity app, I'm trying to replace all fragment transactions by implementing the `Navigation component`.

I've already created a Navigation graph and included the `FragmentContainerView` as a child of the root `ViewGroup` as it was proposed in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#create_a_navigation_graph).

**activity_main.xml**

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Now the problem that I'm currently facing is that the `SharedViewModel` which I am using through the whole app can't be instantiated in the `BaseFragment` anymore.

**BaseFragment.kt**

```
abstract class BaseFragment<E : ViewDataBinding, T : BaseViewModel> : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewModel: T

    lateinit var dataBinding: E

    abstract fun getLayoutResource(): Int

    abstract fun getViewModelClass(): Class<T>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.let {
            // java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class SharedViewModel
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(it).get(getViewModelClass())
            // viewModel = ViewModelProvider(getParentFragment()).get(getViewModelClass()) also doesn't work
        }
    }
...
}
```

**BaseViewModel.kt**

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver
```

**SharedViewModel.kt**

```
abstract class SharedViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
...
}
```

**SharedViewModelImpl.kt**

```
class SharedViewModelImpl(private val repository: AppRepository) : SharedViewModel(){
...
}
```

I've read posts on SO and as well as Medium [articles](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e) that recommend creating the `SharedViewModel` by using  `by navGraphViewModels` like this

```
val viewModel: SharedViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.navigation_graph)
```

but it seems that I still can't combine this approach with the generics that I already have.

**My assumption is that the `Navigation component` can't deal with `abstract` classes.**

How can I overcome this problem by keeping my existing app architecture? Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

@ianhanniballake asked me to post the entire stack trace. So here it is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: at.bwappsandmore.doitagain, PID: 13528
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.bwappsandmore.doitagain/at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.viewModel.SharedViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.base.BaseFragment.onCreate(BaseFragment.kt:31)
        at at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.ui.DisplayDataFragment.onCreate(DisplayDataFragment.kt:85)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2571)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1685)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:264)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:27)
        at at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<at.bwappsandmore.doitagain.viewModel.SharedViewModel> cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
            ... 60 more
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please include the entire stack trace.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ian, thank you so much for replying, I appreciate this a lot, this is the entire stack trace when I am trying to create my ViewModel by `viewModel = ViewModelProvider(it).get(getViewModelClass())`. By using `getParentFragment()` instead of `it` the compiler tells me that the `viewModel` is directly attached in the `MainAcitivity`. I could also share the stack trace when I am using `getParentFragment()` if you like to see it. Once again thank you so much for your help.